# How do I manipulate objects within arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been given two arrays, each of which has several objects within them. I'm trying to make it so that when a certain dropdown selection is made, it pushes that "flight information" into a "flight summary" div, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

```
var possibleDepartureFlights=[{year:2012,month:11,day:13,hour:17,minute:37,price:137.38} and so on]; 

var possibleReturnFlights=[{year:2012,month:11,day:18,hour:21,minute:45,price:189.46} and so on];
```

Each var has 10 objects within the array, each of which has all those properties.

And as a bonus question, I've figured out how to hide a "submit" button when the return flight selected is earlier than the departure, but I can't figure out how to make the submit button come back when a different selection is made!

```
function displayDivs() {
var departureValue = $('#departureFlightsControl').val();
var returnValue = $('#returnFlightsControl').val();
if (departureValue != "default") {
    $('.CumulativeSummary').addClass('totalAvailable');
    $('.DepartureSummary').addClass('flightChosen');
}
if (returnValue != "default") {
    $('.CumulativeSummary').addClass('totalAvailable');
    $('.ReturnSummary').addClass('flightChosen');
}
if ($('#returnFlightsControl').val() < $('#departureFlightsControl').val()) {
    $('.SubmitArea').hide();
}
```

Sorry if this question is vague! I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing (and I'm not even really sure what to Google for to find the answer to my problem(s)). Please use small words, as if you're speaking to a child. Thanks!

Comment: `var month = possibleDepartureFlights[0].month;` First access the array, then you have the object an can access it's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really too broad, anyways... Suppose you have following

```
var possibleDepartureFlights=[
    {year:2012,month:10,day:13,hour:10,minute:37,price:137.38}, 
    {year:2012,month:11,day:15,hour:17,minute:47,price:150.50} 
];
```

The `possibleDepartureFlights` is an array of two objects and the first element of the array is the first object and it's `{year:2012,month:10,day:13,hour:10,minute:37,price:137.38}` and it's index is `0` and the second element in your `possibleDepartureFlights` array is the second object and it's `{year:2012,month:11,day:15,hour:17,minute:47,price:150.50}` and it's index is `1`. Now, if you want to access the `month` property of the first item of the array then you can write like

```
alert(possibleDepartureFlights[0].month); // this will alert 10
```

For the `month` of the second item/object in the array you can write

```
    alert(possibleDepartureFlights[1].month); // this will alert 11
```

To loop through the `array` and print out the each property of every objects, you can try this

```
for(i=0;i<possibleDepartureFlights.length;i++)
{
    console.log(possibleDepartureFlights[i].year);
    console.log(possibleDepartureFlights[i].month);
    console.log(possibleDepartureFlights[i].hour);
    console.log(possibleDepartureFlights[i].minute);
    console.log(possibleDepartureFlights[i].price);
}
```

[**An Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/unx3L/)

Remember, this is only a short example and there are more about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) in `JavaScript`. Also remember that you can `loop` an object with [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) like [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Also [this one](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1205) could be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Sorry my question is so broad, I'm struggling to understand arrays/objects and how they interact with the rest of the code, so this was helpful.